# Unable to resolve module in React Native IOS, but works in Android

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-apollo

The app is built successfully in X-code, but this error comes up right on start:

```
Unable to resolve module 
`../node_modules/react-native/node_modules/react-apollo/react-apollo.browser.umd.js` 
from `/Users/lau/Documents/project/watch/mobile/src/Screen.js`: 
could not resolve 
`/Users/lau/Documents/project/watch/mobile/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/react-apollo/react-apollo.browser.umd.js' 
as a file nor as a folder
```

I think the problem is due to the extra  `/node_modules/react-native/` in the path.

There are files in `../node_modules/react-apollo/react-apollo.browser.umd.js` but not in `../node_modules/react-native/node_modules/react-apollo/react-apollo.browser.umd.js`. I don't understand why the path is prefixed with the unnecessary `/node_modules/react-native/` in React Native IOS. Is it caused by the Search Path in the build settings?

Here is how I import react-apollo module in Screen.js:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import {Navigation} from 'react-native-navigation';
import {ApolloProvider} from "react-apollo";
```

The build settings:
[image]
[image]

package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.2.7",
    "apollo-cache-persist": "^0.1.1",
    "apollo-client": "^2.3.8",
    "apollo-client-preset": "^1.0.8",
    "apollo-engine": "^1.1.2",
    "apollo-link": "^1.2.2",
    "apollo-link-batch-http": "^1.2.2",
    "apollo-link-context": "^1.0.8",
    "apollo-link-persisted-queries": "^0.2.1",
    "apollo-link-state": "^0.4.1",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-apollo": "^2.1.11",
    "react-native": "0.56.0",
    "react-native-navigation": "^2.0.2471"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted the ./nodule_modules, run `npm install` and remove this block from `.babelrc`

```
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "alias": {
        "react-apollo": "react-apollo/react-apollo.browser.umd.js"
      }
    }]
  ]
```

Things are working fine. 
Maybe there are conflicts in the versions of some apollo modules.